# Disabling close button in messageboxa with the use of sc_close

Tags: c, winapi

I had this problem for quite a while now.

In my message box, I have a cancel button. I don't want the close button to interfere because my cancel button does something, which shouldn't happen if I press the close button.

I used a loop-and-find trick, but when I open a folder that also has the same title as the message box, the code disables the close button of Explorer, which is very annoying.

This was what I used to disable the close button that also interferes with other windows that have the same title:

```
DWORD WINAPI CreateMessageBox(void *argr){
    *(int*)argr = MessageBoxA( NULL, 
        "Time is past active hours\nPlease save your work\nSystem is shutting down in 1 minute.\n", 
        "Warning", 
        MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONSTOP|MB_SYSTEMMODAL );

    return 0;
}
```

```
thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, CreateMessageBox, &opt, 0, NULL);
while (!(msg = FindWindow(NULL, "Warning")));
style = GetWindowLongPtr(msg, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtr(msg, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_SYSMENU);
WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);
```

But now, I read somewhere that there is this `SC_CLOSE` thing that also disables the close button exclusively to that window. How do I use it? I've gone through some posts about it, but none of them uses `MessageBox()` and that just overwhelms me.

Please, can somebody help me?

Comment: How do I use SetWindowsHookeEx tho? sorry for this I'm just really not that good with win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `FindWindow()` is not specifying a class name, thus it will find *any* top-level window with a matching title. In your case, an Explorer window. Provide the actual class name for the MessageBox window, which is `"#32770"`, eg:

```
msg = FindWindow("#32770", "Warning")
```

However, there is a much more reliable approach that doesn't invoke searching window titles - get rid of the calls to `CreateThread()` and `FindWindow()` completely, and instead make the thread that calls `MessageBox()` use a local  [`WH_CBT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v%3Dvs.85)) hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) to catch the `HWND` that `MessageBox()` creates, then you can manipulate that window as desired, eg:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyCBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        ((CBT_CREATEWND*)lParam)->lpcs->style & ~WS_SYSMENU;
    }

    /* alternatively:
    if (nCode == HCBT_ACTIVATE)
    {
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
        LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style & ~WS_SYSMENU);
    }
    */

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

...

HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, &MyCBTProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

opt = MessageBoxA(NULL,
    "Time is past active hours\nPlease save your work\nSystem is shutting down in 1 minute.\n",
    "Warning",
    MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONSTOP|MB_SYSTEMMODAL);

if (hHook)
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
```

Alternatively, simply use [`TaskDialog()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialog) or [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) instead of `MessageBox()`. A [Task Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/task-dialogs) does not have a close button in the title bar, unless you call [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) with the `TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION` flag enabled:

> Indicates that the dialog should be able to be closed using Alt-F4, Escape, **and the title bar's close button** even if no cancel button is specified in either the `dwCommonButtons` or `pButtons` members.

```
TaskDialog(NULL, NULL,
    L"Warning",
    L"Time is past active hours",
    L"Please save your work\nSystem is shutting down in 1 minute.",
    TDCBF_OK_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON,
    TD_ERROR_ICON,
    &opt);
```

Comment: you mentioned that it catches the HWND that MessageBox() create, does it return it? from `SetWindowsHookEx`? I tried to execute it but it's still there the x button

Comment: @java.begginer my example shows you how to access the HWND. No, the hook does not *return* the HWND, but several of its *notifications* provide access to the HWND.

Comment: So i don't need to have `TASKDIALOGCONFIG`anymore right? I've searched and they've been using `TASKDIALOGCONFIG` I guess it was specific to the language they're using? And I'm on C so I can directly use `TaskDialog` right away, am I right? Just like in your code snippet

Comment: @java.begginer `TASKDIALOGCONFIG` is used only with `TaskDialogIndirect()`, which provides more flexibility than `TaskDialog()`. If you don't need the extra features that `TaskDialogIndirect()` provides, then `TaskDialog()` is easier to use. This has nothing to do with programming languages. Any language that is compatible with C style DLLs can use Win32 functions.

Comment: I got it, thank you. I just resorted on using `SetWindowsHookEx` in conjunction with `CallNextHookEx` and it worked